# hibernate-schema-plugin validate goal

Tags: hibernate, maven-plugin

has anyone here used the hibernate-schema-plugin from vecna technologies? I was wondering how to execute the validate goal from the command line. Here's the documentation: https://github.com/vecnatechnologies/hibernate-schema-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It's hibernate-schema:validate